# How can I avoid to set all my component's modules in an activity to inject dependencies with Dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using Dagger 2 to inject dependencies and MVP as my application design pattern.

I have 2 activities(`MainActivity` and `LoginActivity`). Each one implements an interface (`MainView` and `LoginView` respectly) and have an associated module (`LoginModule` and `MainModule`). On the other hand, I have a `MainComponent` which uses the 2 modules. The problem is the following: 
If I'm trying to inject dependencies in `MainActivity`, I just need the `MainModule`, not the `LoginModule`, but the `MainComponent` uses the 2 modules in his graph. So, I have to set the 2 modules (correct me if I'm wrong), It should be something like this:

```
public void setupComponent(MyApplicationComponent appComponent){
   DaggerMainComponent.builder()
       .myApplicationComponent(appComponent)
       .mainModule(new MainModule(this))
       .loginModule(new LoginModule(???))
       .build.inject(this);
}
```

When I inject dependencies in `MainActivity` I just need to set the `MainModule` and in `LoginActivity` the `LoginModule`, not both. How can I do it?

LoginModule:

```
@Module
public class LoginModule {

    private LoginView loginView;

    public LoginModule(LoginView view) {
        loginView = view;
    }

    @Provides
    public LoginView provideLoginView() {
        return loginView;
    }
```

MainModule:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {
    private MainView mainView;

    public MainModule(MainView mainView){
        this.mainView=mainView;
    }

    @Provides MainView provideMainView(){
        return mainView;
    }
}
```

As you can see `MainModule` and `LoginModule`, both have one parameter in their constructors (`MainView` and `LoginView`). So knowing that `MainActivity` implements `MainView` and `LoginModule` implements `LoginView`, If I'm in `MainActivity` and I want to inject dependencies I need to set `MainModule` like this: `.mainModule(new MainModule(this)).build.inject(this)`. But what about `LoginModule`? How can I avoid to set it in this activity without having to remove it from `MainComponent`'s modules? or how can I set it (I can't use "THIS" in `.loginModule(new LoginModule(this))` because of `MainActivity` implements `MainView` but not `LoginView`)?

MainComponent:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(
        dependencies = MyApplicationComponent.class,
        modules = {LoginModule.class, MainModule.class}
)

public interface MainComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    LoginPresenterImp getLoginPresenter();
    MainPresenterImp getMainPresenter():
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `MainActivity` implements `MainView`, why do you need to inject an instance of `MainView` into `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoginModule and MainModule should have their own components.

I would suggest making a LoginComponent and a MainComponent and then adding them to MyApplicationComponent as subcomponents.

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(
    modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(Application application);

    MainComponent plus(MainModule mainModule);
    LoginComponent plus(LoginModule loginModule);

}
```

////

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(
    modules = {
            MainModule.class,
    }
)
public interface MainComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

}
```

////

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(
    modules = {
            LoginModule.class,
    }
)
public interface LoginComponent {

    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);

}
```

then to inject your activities

```
public void setupComponent(ApplicationComponent appComponent){
appComponent.plus(new MainModule(this)).inject(this)
}

public void setupComponent(ApplicationComponent appComponent){
appComponent.plus(new LoginModule(this)).inject(this)
}
```